# WHOIS: Extra responses?

Tags: whois

I recently decided to run a WHOIS query on Microsoft.com using the Linux whois client. I was greeted by a flood of obviously non-Microsoft.com domains that begin with the string "Microsoft.com" (many of which are pretty explicit) followed by the WHOIS results for the actual Microsoft.com domain.

Here is an (edited) sample of the given response (if you aren't scared of a few swear words, go ahead and 'whois' them yourself;):

```
   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ARE.*******.**********.NET.NS-NOT-IN-SERVICE.COM
   IP Address: 216.127.80.46
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.CAN.**.****.*******.AT.SECZY.COM
   IP Address: 209.187.114.147
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.EENGURRA.COM
   IP Address: 184.168.46.68
   Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
   Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
   Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.FILLS.ME.WITH.BELLIGERENCE.NET
   IP Address: 130.58.82.232
   Registrar: CPS-DATENSYSTEME GMBH
   Whois Server: whois.cps-datensysteme.de
   Referral URL: http://www.cps-datensysteme.de

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.HAS.A.PRESENT.COMING.FROM.HUGHESMISSILES.COM
   IP Address: 66.154.11.27
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.A.MESS.TIMPORTER.CO.UK
   Registrar: MELBOURNE IT, LTD. D/B/A INTERNET NAMES WORLDWIDE
   Whois Server: whois.melbourneit.com
   Referral URL: http://www.melbourneit.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.A.STEAMING.HEAP.OF.*******-********.NET
   IP Address: 63.99.165.11
   Registrar: 1 & 1 INTERNET AG
   Whois Server: whois.schlund.info
   Referral URL: http://1and1.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.HOSTED.ON.PROFITHOSTING.NET
   IP Address: 66.49.213.213
   Registrar: NAME.COM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.name.com
   Referral URL: http://www.name.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.IN.BED.WITH.CURTYV.COM
   IP Address: 216.55.187.193
   Registrar: HOSTOPIA.COM INC. D/B/A APLUS.NET
   Whois Server: whois.names4ever.com
   Referral URL: http://www.aplus.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.HOSTED.BY.ACTIVEDOMAINDNS.NET
   IP Address: 217.148.161.5
   Registrar: ENOM, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.enom.com
   Referral URL: http://www.enom.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.IS.NOT.YEPPA.ORG
   Registrar: OVH
   Whois Server: whois.ovh.com
   Referral URL: http://www.ovh.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.LIVES.AT.SHAUNEWING.COM
   IP Address: 216.40.250.172
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.LOVES.ME.KOSMAL.NET
   IP Address: 65.75.198.123
   Registrar: GODADDY.COM, LLC
   Whois Server: whois.godaddy.com
   Referral URL: http://registrar.godaddy.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.MAKES.RICKARD.DRINK.SAMBUCA.0800CARRENTAL.COM
   IP Address: 209.85.135.106
   Registrar: KEY-SYSTEMS GMBH
   Whois Server: whois.rrpproxy.net
   Referral URL: http://www.key-systems.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.MATCHES.THIS.STRING.AT.KEYSIGNERS.COM
   IP Address: 85.10.240.254
   Registrar: HETZNER ONLINE AG
   Whois Server: whois.your-server.de
   Referral URL: http://www.hetzner.de

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.MORE.INFO.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
   IP Address: 203.36.226.2
   Registrar: INSTRA CORPORATION PTY, LTD.
   Whois Server: whois.instra.net
   Referral URL: http://www.instra.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.RAWKZ.MUH.WERLD.MENTALFLOSS.CA
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.SHOULD.GIVE.UP.BECAUSE.LINUXISGOD.COM
   IP Address: 65.160.248.13
   Registrar: GKG.NET, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.gkg.net
   Referral URL: http://www.gkg.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.SOFTWARE.IS.NOT.USED.AT.REG.RU
   Registrar: MELBOURNE IT, LTD. D/B/A INTERNET NAMES WORLDWIDE
   Whois Server: whois.melbourneit.com
   Referral URL: http://www.melbourneit.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.WAREZ.AT.TOPLIST.GULLI.COM
   IP Address: 80.190.192.33
   Registrar: COREHUB, S.R.L.
   Whois Server: whois.corehub.net
   Referral URL: http://www.corehub.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.BEATEN.WITH.MY.SPANNER.NET
   IP Address: 216.127.80.46
   Registrar: ASCIO TECHNOLOGIES, INC. DANMARK - FILIAL AF ASCIO TECHNOLOGIES, INC. USA
   Whois Server: whois.ascio.com
   Referral URL: http://www.ascio.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.WILL.BE.SLAPPED.IN.THE.FACE.BY.MY.****.******.SPANNER.NET
   IP Address: 216.127.80.46
   Registrar: ASCIO TECHNOLOGIES, INC. DANMARK - FILIAL AF ASCIO TECHNOLOGIES, INC. USA
   Whois Server: whois.ascio.com
   Referral URL: http://www.ascio.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZ.IS.0WNED.AND.HAX0RED.BY.SUB7.NET
   IP Address: 207.44.240.96
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZ.***.*****.AT.WWW.********COMMUNITY.COM
   IP Address: 69.41.185.194
   Registrar: TUCOWS DOMAINS INC.
   Whois Server: whois.tucows.com
   Referral URL: http://domainhelp.opensrs.net

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZ.MORE.DETAILS.AT.WWW.BEYONDWHOIS.COM
   IP Address: 203.36.226.2
   Registrar: INSTRA CORPORATION PTY, LTD.
   Whois Server: whois.instra.net
   Referral URL: http://www.instra.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.IM.ELITE.WANNABE.TOO.WWW.PLUS613.NET
   IP Address: 64.251.18.228
   Registrar: REGISTER4LESS, INC.
   Whois Server: whois.register4less.com
   Referral URL: http://register4less.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.GET.ONE.MILLION.DOLLARS.AT.WWW.UNIMUNDI.COM
   IP Address: 209.126.190.70
   Registrar: PDR LTD. D/B/A PUBLICDOMAINREGISTRY.COM
   Whois Server: whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com
   Referral URL: http://www.PublicDomainRegistry.com

   Server Name: MICROSOFT.COM.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.IS.A.GREAT.COMPANY.ITREBAL.COM
   IP Address: 97.107.132.202
   Registrar: GANDI SAS
   Whois Server: whois.gandi.net
   Referral URL: http://www.gandi.net

   Domain Name: MICROSOFT.COM
   Registrar: MARKMONITOR INC.
   Whois Server: whois.markmonitor.com
   Referral URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
   Name Server: NS1.MSFT.NET
   Name Server: NS2.MSFT.NET
   Name Server: NS3.MSFT.NET
   Name Server: NS4.MSFT.NET
   Status: clientDeleteProhibited
   Status: clientTransferProhibited
   Status: clientUpdateProhibited
   Status: serverDeleteProhibited
   Status: serverTransferProhibited
   Status: serverUpdateProhibited
   Updated Date: 09-oct-2014
   Creation Date: 02-may-1991
   Expiration Date: 03-may-2021

>>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 18 Nov 2014 17:04:45 GMT <<<

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the 
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is 
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration 
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring 
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to 
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

TERMS OF USE: You are not authorized to access or query our Whois 
database through the use of electronic processes that are high-volume and 
automated except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or 
modify existing registrations; the Data in VeriSign Global Registry 
Services' ("VeriSign") Whois database is provided by VeriSign for 
information purposes only, and to assist persons in obtaining information 
about or related to a domain name registration record. VeriSign does not 
guarantee its accuracy. By submitting a Whois query, you agree to abide 
by the following terms of use: You agree that you may use this Data only 
for lawful purposes and that under no circumstances will you use this Data 
to: (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass 
unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail, telephone, 
or facsimile; or (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes 
that apply to VeriSign (or its computer systems). The compilation, 
repackaging, dissemination or other use of this Data is expressly 
prohibited without the prior written consent of VeriSign. You agree not to 
use electronic processes that are automated and high-volume to access or 
query the Whois database except as reasonably necessary to register 
domain names or modify existing registrations. VeriSign reserves the right 
to restrict your access to the Whois database in its sole discretion to ensure 
operational stability.  VeriSign may restrict or terminate your access to the 
Whois database for failure to abide by these terms of use. VeriSign 
reserves the right to modify these terms at any time. 

The Registry database contains ONLY .COM, .NET, .EDU domains and
Registrars.
Using server whois.markmonitor.com.
Query string: "microsoft.com"

Domain Name: microsoft.com
Registry Domain ID: 2724960_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2014-10-15T04:00:12-0700
Creation Date: 1991-05-01T21:00:00-0700
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2021-05-02T21:00:00-0700
Registrar: MarkMonitor, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Organization: Microsoft Corporation
Registrant Street: One Microsoft Way, 
Registrant City: Redmond
Registrant State/Province: WA
Registrant Postal Code: 98052
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.4258828080
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: +1.4259367329
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: domains@microsoft.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: Domain Administrator
Admin Organization: Microsoft Corporation
Admin Street: One Microsoft Way, 
Admin City: Redmond
Admin State/Province: WA
Admin Postal Code: 98052
Admin Country: US
Admin Phone: +1.4258828080
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: +1.4259367329
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: domains@microsoft.com
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: MSN Hostmaster
Tech Organization: Microsoft Corporation
Tech Street: One Microsoft Way, 
Tech City: Redmond
Tech State/Province: WA
Tech Postal Code: 98052
Tech Country: US
Tech Phone: +1.4258828080
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: +1.4259367329
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: msnhst@microsoft.com
Name Server: ns4.msft.net
Name Server: ns2.msft.net
Name Server: ns1.msft.net
Name Server: ns3.msft.net
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2014-11-18T08:58:20-0800 <<<

The Data in MarkMonitor.com's WHOIS database is provided by MarkMonitor.com for
information purposes, and to assist persons in obtaining information about or
related to a domain name registration record.  MarkMonitor.com does not guarantee
its accuracy.  By submitting a WHOIS query, you agree that you will use this Data
only for lawful purposes and that, under no circumstances will you use this Data to:
 (1) allow, enable, or otherwise support the transmission of mass unsolicited,
     commercial advertising or solicitations via e-mail (spam); or
 (2) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that apply to
     MarkMonitor.com (or its systems).
MarkMonitor.com reserves the right to modify these terms at any time.
By submitting this query, you agree to abide by this policy.

MarkMonitor is the Global Leader in Online Brand Protection.

MarkMonitor Domain Management(TM)
MarkMonitor Brand Protection(TM)
MarkMonitor AntiPiracy(TM)
MarkMonitor AntiFraud(TM)
Professional and Managed Services

Visit MarkMonitor at http://www.markmonitor.com
Contact us at +1.8007459229
In Europe, at +44.02032062220
--
```

Obviously, all of these domains except the last are not actually owned by Microsoft. So, my question is: how exactly does this happen and why I getting responses for a plethora of whois servers? The commonality between the responses shows me that the a search was done somewhere for something like Microsoft.com.*, but where is all this extra information pulled from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Verisign whois service does a partial search also in registered nameservers, hence those are all output. Verisign could be smarter about this...

The same thing happens with other domains, e.g. google.com, apple.com.